# Maximum vector contained in a cube (lattice)

Tags: integer-lattices

We have some lattice $$\Gamma=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}v_i$$where the length of each basis vector, as well as the angle between every two vectors, is bounded. Is there an upper bound for $|\Gamma\bigcap [0,1]^n|?$

Comment: How many vertices on an $n$-dimensional cube?  If it's an integer lattice, then vertices are only possible places of intersection.

Comment: I guess there might be some misunderstanding. For instance, take $n=1, v_1=1/2$, then there are three vectors $0,v_1,2v_1$ in the intersection, in which $v_1$ is not a vertex.

Comment: Ok.  I assumed that the lattice vectors were integer-valued.